# Using the Old Camera on a Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: raspicam, pi-zero

As was [recently announced](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/zero-grows-camera-connector/), the Raspberry Pi Zero (V1.3) now supports the foundation's camera. It was also announced that the new Zero has a smaller connector and requires a different ribbon cable that is used on the larger form factor of the other models.

Is the Raspberry Pi Zero compatible with the older camera ([5 MP](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/camera-module/)), or only the newer model ([8 MP](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/camera-module-v2/)) that was recently released?

Comment: You are mistaken about the V1.2 That's the old one (Q4/2015). New is V1.3 as of Q2/2016. See http://elinux.org/RPi_HardwareHistory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As clarified in a [tweet](https://twitter.com/Raspberry_Pi/status/732192217230680064) from the Foundation's official twitter account, both camera models are supported by the RPi zero.

The only difference between the camera connectors is the form factor. No software changes are needed for compatibility. And any camera presently sold by the foundation will work for any model of RPi currently in production. Assuming you have the right ribbon cable.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adafruit.com (among others) sells camera cables for Zeros.  Much cheaper than buying a whole different camera.  I might have seen them on Aliexpress.