# RPI Camera Module with Pico

Tags: camera, pi-pico

does anybody know if it is possible to use the RPI Camera module (Rev. 1.3) with the Pico or any other RP2040 board?

Comment: Define "possible". It certainly wouldn't violate any laws of physics, so it's likely possible to do given enough time and resources. Worst case, you could make a custom chip which translates the camera data stream into something the Pico could read.

Comment: Thank you very much for this helpful reply, Dimitry,

Comment: Note that there are microcontroller-friendly camera modules out there, such as OV7670 or OV5640.

Comment: I know. I use the OV7670.

Comment: Perhaps this answers the question https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/47573/using-the-old-camera-on-a-raspberry-pi-zero

Answer (score 3):

No it is not.

The devices do not have a common interface (there is no way for the Pico to read/write the RPi camera module hardware).